# Ошибка импорта из CSV в postgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

Перевёл excel таблицу в csv, через \IMPORT table FROM хочу загрузить данные в таблицу. Ругается на первую строчку (после шапки), третий столбец. Тип данных text, значение ‘3’. Ошибка «нет данных для столбца ‘column’». Строка 2.
Не могу понять с чем связано. Подскажите, что надо проверить

Comment: *что надо проверить* Формат данных и его соответствие формату целевой таблицы.

Comment: приведите структуру таблицы, sql-строку ипорта и пару строк, нам не видно.